# A property dealing with complete metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

I came across a property in a textbook that caught my eye. The property is: If $X$ is a complete metric space, then the intersection of any two dense $G_{\delta}$-subsets of $X$ is dense in $X$.

This property seems simple, but I am having trouble figuring out the proof. Can anyone help me out on this one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an immediate consequence of the [Baire category theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem) and the fact that if $G$ is a $G_\delta$ in $X$, then $G=\bigcap_{n\in N}U_n$ for some open sets $U_n$ in $X$, and if in addition $G$ is dense in $X$, then so is each of the sets $U_n$.